# iOS display message to user from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, accelerometer

My client gave me a requirement. My app is monitoring accelerometer data from background. He want to show some messages to user from background depending on the data. It will be like local notification. this message will be removed if desired value is received through the sensor.

How do I implement such feature? I've tried local notification. But my sensor reading frequency is too high, therefore lots of notifications are getting generated. If I want to cancel the notifications, after sometime, mobile gets soft rebooted.

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: Save frequency values upto 10 or 20 max in array when array reach to max  range (10 or 20) and average it display the local notification. so that you can avoid multiple notifications

Comment: Use a Bool flag to set one notification. And after that when user will see the notification then try to set another one !

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_accelerometer.htm and http://www.appcoda.com/ios-maze-game-tutorial-accelerometer/

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I have found a solution, don't know my client will like it or not. update frequency has been set to 3 seconds. and therefore I'm getting time to remove the existing notifications from the recent notifications by setting the badges to 0.